# Change JavaFX TableView Vertical ScrollBar value programmatically

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

**Description:**

Let's assume that we have a simple JavaFX `TableView`, and it has 50 items. I want to scroll vertically at **0.49**.

You can use the example from Oracle Tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm )

---

So i am using:

```
ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) tableViewer.lookup(".scrollbar:vertical");
verticalBar.setValue(0.49);
```

But it doesn't work....

---

I can't find a way to work around with this . The `.scrollTo(...)`->[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo-int-) doesn't give that precision . I need the vertical bar to be exactly at (**0.49** or **0.24** or **...** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a typo, a `scrollbar` instead of `scroll-bar`. This is a correct line:

```
ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) tableViewer.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
```

Comment: Oh my fault , i had that but i didn't added it by mistake on the question during copy pasting the code.... `Although i double checked it using your answer by again it doesn't work... Does it work for you ?`

Comment: `verticalBar.getValue();` returns correctly `0.27` for example but it does not works omg [ not moving the vertical scroll bar  , or moving it sometimes 1/10 ] , i am on JavaFX Application Thread . Using an `observableArrayList` to populate the `TableView` with items... I think it doesn't fire the Event . The `.scrollTo(index)` works immediatelly ...

Comment: Can you create a MCVE that reproduces the issue? I put that code in my own project where I have few `TableViews`, ran it from different places, even with a heavy thread running in the background, and it works as expected.

Perhaps you modify the table content after or before?

Comment: I am populating the `ObservableArrayList` [which i have added using `tableView.setItems(list);` ] though a `Service<Boolean>` and then when the Service is done [ every time is successful , i am checking that] , i am using `tableView.refresh();` and after that i am adding the code for the `scrollbar.setValue();` . Hope this helps .

Comment: I found the problem . I was populating the `ObservableArrayList` from the external Thread without `Platform.runLater();` , but now i am using an `ArrayList `and after populating it i use `ObservableArrayList .addAll(arrayList);` inside a `Platform.runLater();` , as i can see it works smoothly now :) . I have a question here [ your opinion ]  , is it better to use the above solution creating an new `ArrayList` , or using `tableView.setItems(null);` , then populate the `ObservableList` and finally use again `tableView.setItems(ObservableList );`?

Comment: Adding items to an `ObservableArrayList` is few times slower than adding them to a normal `ArrayList`... but it's still very fast, so I would not try to optimize it. Copying won't be an issue either. Use what's more readable to you.

Comment: I have tested the first way for 15 minutes . It seems to increase a lot the work of garbage collector . I see 200 + mb of ram in my application using it [after 5 minutes of random copying.. ]. That's the only negative i see here... :) . It needs a ton of time to be garbage collected... that `ArrayList` , besides that it works like charm . Is there a way to get rid of it faster ? I mean make it `array=null` after using `ObservableArrayList .addAll(arrayList);`